# Bootstrap output matrix missing

Tags: r, spatstat

When I try to calculate Gest in spatstat I get the error:

> bootstrap output matrix missing.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You mean the R package http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/index.html?  A code sample would go a long way here...

Answer (score 1):

I think that "bootstrap output matrix missing" is a fairly generic error, and (unless someone has explicit experience with your case) I would imagine that more information is needed to solve this.

Without more information, I would suggest that you debug the Gest function.  You have two good options for that:

1) Use the `debug()` function:

```
 debug(Gest)
```

Now run your code.  Then you can walk through the Gest function and see where is breaks.  Before that point, look at all the environment variables by (for instance) using `ls()` and see if any assumptions are broken.  Presumably something isn't being set correctly.

2) Use `recover`:

```
 option(error=recover)
```

Then you will go into `browser` mode whenever the error occurs, and you can explore the workspace at that point.

Answer (score 1):

This error message does not originate from the spatstat package.

To identify the location of the error, type `traceback()` immediately after the error has occurred. This will give you a list of the nested commands that were being executed at the time the error occurred. The top one is the location which raised the error.